# Can I customize how often Ubuntu One syncs to the cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, cloud

I sync my programming workspace to the cloud using Ubuntu One. Everything works pretty well, but since I modify and save many files quite frequently, Ubuntu One is constantly syncing and gets backed up. Is there any way to customize how often Ubuntu One syncs to the cloud? For example, have it only synchronize every half-hour?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it manually, disconnecting from Ubuntu One service and reconnecting when you want the syncronization. With the [Ubuntu One Indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-gets-a-ppa/), mentioned also on previous answer, you can easily disconnect and connect, clicking on that indicator menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, not available for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin!

Comment: yes... it seems to be available, see PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-extras See also here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-adds-new-features

Answer (score 0):

I think ubuntu one syncs their file automatically, but you want to make sure it is syncs then you can install the [Ubuntu One indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-gets-a-ppa/) if you don't have one already

UPDATE: Also there is a new Ubuntu One Lens for Unity call [UnityOne](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/drag-and-drop-ubuntuone-file-uploader-for-the-ubuntu-unity-launcher/)

Tell me if it work.

I already double check it, if you save a text/programming file in ubuntu one folder and if you make change to it, it automatically syncs

by the way, are you using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: (I am the OP... I just signed up for an account)

Yes, I am using Natty. And Ubuntu One is syncing automatically. But that's the problem. It syncs too often. I only want it to sync periodically so that it doesn't get backed up with updates.

Comment: I think is possible to force ubuntu one to do that, but I not sure how.

Comment: If you sync less frequently you will get more backed up with updates, not less.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually control the U1 syncdaemon using "u1sdtool". It is terminal-controlled, so using a shell-script reacting to your whishes, you can sync whenever you want. You can find the man page here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/u1sdtool.1.html